# Differences with visual studio 2010 express and 2012 express for opening a c# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I used the express 2010 version for work for a few months before upgrading my system to Windows 8 and visual studio 12 express.  I tried running the visual studio for windows 8 but when i try to open my c# project from my 2010 it tells me that this edition only supports window store apps.

My question is which VS 2012 express version allows me to work on my C# projects?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have VS2012 Express for Windows 8, what you want is VS2012 Express for Windows Desktop

Source:
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop

Comment: i have a time limit, or else i would have marked this as an answer. give me a few minutes lol